# If $H$ is normal in $G$ then $H$ is the kernel of a group homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Show that if $H$ is normal, then it's the kernel of a group homomorphism.

**Attempt**

I proved that if $H$ is the kernel of a group homomorphism, then $H$ is normal. But how can I prove the converse ? I tried to construct something as $f:G\to G$ s.t. $f(gh)=g$. Then $\ker f=H$, but I have difficulty to show that $f$ is indeed a homomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$H$ is the kernel of the canonical surjection $G \to G/H$ where $G/H$ is the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group).

Answer (score 3):

Because $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, you know that the quotient $G/H$ comes with a canonical structure of group, such that the projection $\pi: G\rightarrow G/H$ is a group morphism, with kernel exactly $H$.

Answer (score 1):

You send $g\in G$ to the coset $gH=Hg$ (this equality is true by normality), and you can show that the obvious group operation on cosets is well-defined, and associative, with $H$ as identity and the obvious inverse. The kernel of this map, which is a homomorphism, is precisely $H$.